# Is there an MTA that can store TLS authentication details securely?

Tags: security, smtp, mta

I'm setting up my email client (mutt) on a new laptop (running Mac OSX Lion).  I want to use SMTP with TLS for sending email.  Searching for SMTP+Mutt+TLS reveals that Mutt's inbuilt secure SMTP stuff is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.  That's okay as I can use an external MTA to send the mail.  However, as I want to use TLS then I need to provide it with a username and password.  Trouble is, if I want to have that done automatically then all the MTAs I've looked at so far (such as postfix) seem to store the password in an easily accessible manner (well, in a manner a bit too plain for my paranoid liking).

So my question is: Is there an MTA with SMTP+TLS support which can store the password in a secure manner?

Comment: How can it be stored "securely" if the client must know the plaintext?

Comment: @grawity I don't know much about how SMTP+TLS authentication works - does the client send the password in plaintext?  How do programs like Thunderbird or OSX's Mail store the password securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *msmtp* MTA can store credentials in OS X Keychain, if it was compiled with `--with-macosx-keyring` option. (See, for example, [*msmtp* on MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/17987).)

To use this functionality, create a keychain item named `smtp://<smtp-host>` of kind "Internet password" (replacing `<smtp-host>` with your SMTP server's address):

```
    Name: smtp.freemail.example
    Kind: Internet password
 Account: joe.smith
   Where: smtp://smtp.freemail.example
```

Comment: This works just great!  Thank you very much for figuring out what I wanted.